# cursor.execute value sub string does not work

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to load the value +02:00  with format i.e. -

```
mysql> select SUBSTR('2016-01-12T14:29:31.000+02:00',24,6);
+02:00
```

### Python :

```
csv_data = csv.reader(open('aaaa.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO time2(col1, \
         EventTimeZone)' \
'VALUES(%s,SUBSTR(\'%s\',24,6))',
         (row[0],row[1]))
```

how to validate the query in Python `cursor.execute` to sub string the incoming value..?

Comment: Show us sample CSV data please.

Comment: cat aaaa.csv
45123,2016-01-12T14:29:31.000+02:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a function inside a `VALUES` clause in an `INSERT`.  But, we can rephrase your query to be an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO time2 (col1, EventTimeZone)
SELECT row[0], SUBSTR(row[1], 24, 6)
FROM dual;
```

Here is my best guess as to what the Python code would be:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO time2 (col1, EventTimeZone) \
    SELECT %s, SUBSTR('%s', 24, 6) \
    FROM dual",
    (row[0], row[1]))
```

Comment: Not sure  , doesn't work..  mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2016-01-12T14:29:31.000+02:00'', 24, 6)     FROM dual' at line 1")

Comment: There is either an escaping problem, or your `row` data has a problem.  In any case, you may verify that the raw MySQL query I gave you is working.

Comment: @luckyday Can you `print` the query string to the console?  My guess now is that some of your CSV data has a problem.  You'll have to fix your data before proceeding further.

Comment: Thanks Tim for suggestion, query was successful. It seems a data reading problem then...

Comment: Substring on python side worked aswell !:) (row[0],row[1][23:29]))

Comment: Thank you for the help !